# Custom font works on a desktop browser not a mobile device

Tags: ios, css, macos, fonts, font-face

I want to include a custom font in a website I'm working on. When I went to test it, it was rendering just fine on my Macbook but not my iPhone.

I have been declaring them in my stylsheet like this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: JosenfinSans;
src: url("./fonts/JosenfinSans-Bold.ttf") format("truetype");
font-weight: bold; }
```

Is there anything that I have been doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like are you loading the font from a local directory on your laptop which is not present on your phone. Suggest you source it from Google Fonts https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Josefin+Sans. This way it should work for all devices.